# Outputting CSV to table using PHP creates extra head

Tags: php, html-table, import-from-csv

I have this simple function to output a table from a CSV file. The problem is it creates an extra thead.

```
function MSC_Show_Tables($attr) {

    $rows = 1;

    if (($handle = fopen($attr['csvfile'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $priceTable = '<table class="msc-prices-tables">';
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $numRows = count($row);
            if($rows == 1) {
                $priceTable .= '<thead class="msc-table-head"><tr><th>'.$row[0].'</th><th>'.$row[1].'</th><th>'.$row[2].'</th></tr><thead><tbody>';
            } else {
                $priceTable .= '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</td><td>'.$row[2].'</td></tr>';
            }
            $rows++;
        }
        return $priceTable.'</tbody></table>';
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

This is the HTML it produces

```
&lt;table class="msc-prices-tables"&gt;

&lt;thead class="msc-table-head"&gt;...&lt;/thead&gt;

&lt;thead&gt;&lt;/thead&gt;

&lt;tbody&gt;...&lt;/tbody&gt;

&lt;/table&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line has 2 `<thead>`'s and no `</thead>` so your browser is probably correcting this mistake and adding the extra thead

```
$priceTable .= '<thead class="msc-table-head"><tr><th>'.$row[0]
            .'</th><th>'.$row[1].'</th><th>'.$row[2]
            .'</th></tr><thead><tbody>';
//----------------------^^^^^^^
```

So change to

```
$priceTable .= '<thead class="msc-table-head"><tr><th>'.$row[0]
            .'</th><th>'.$row[1].'</th><th>'.$row[2]
            .'</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
// ---------------------^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I hate it when I miss the obvious.

Comment: We all do! But we all do it so dont sweat it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your closing `<thead>` is missing the leading slash. It should be `</thead>`